# JnativeHook creates freezing problem on MacOS

Tags: java, javafx, jar, jnativehook

I'm doing a program that calculates keyboard mouse mobility on Windows, Mac, and Linux with **JAVA**. I'm using **JNativeHook** for get keyboard and mouse moves. It works fine in Windows and Linux, but after 10-15 minutes on MacOS , pc is freezing and I have to restart the computer.

I've tried unregister JnativeHook (`GlobalScreen.unregisterNativeHook();`) and register it again (`GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();`) every 10 seconds. Now i am having the problem every 2-3 days. 10 minutes to 2-3 days, but this is not the exact solution.

This not my latest code, but the problem is the basic code
https://github.com/erYunusTR/MouseKeyboardListener

The problem occurs when you run the application as .app(MacOS App), it does not occur when you run it as jar or run on ide

Have you ever had a Mac user living this before? or do you have suggestions?

Comment: Hi, i have exatcly the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I unregister(`GlobalScreen.unregisterNativeHook()`) every 10 seconds and register(`GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook()`) again.This is my workaround

Comment: Ok, I will implement the same workaround. THX!